# DataContractSerializer Readobject returns null for custom object

Tags: .net, xml, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, datacontractserializer

I am trying to implement SOAP middleware in .net CORE and in order to retrieve XML into DataContract object I see it doesn't get values of custom objects defined in Service contract.

```
  private object[] GetRequestArguments(Message requestMessage, OperationDescription operation)
    {
        var parameters = operation.DispatchMethod.GetParameters();
        var arguments = new List<object>();

        // Deserialize request wrapper and object
        using (var xmlReader = requestMessage.GetReaderAtBodyContents())
        {
            // Find the element for the operation's data
            xmlReader.ReadStartElement(operation.Name, operation.Contract.Namespace);

            for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
            {
                var parameterName = parameters[i].GetCustomAttribute<MessageParameterAttribute>()?.Name ?? parameters[i].Name;
                xmlReader.MoveToStartElement(parameterName, operation.Contract.Namespace);
                if (xmlReader.IsStartElement(parameterName, operation.Contract.Namespace))
                {
                    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(parameters[i].ParameterType, parameterName, operation.Contract.Namespace);
                    arguments.Add(serializer.ReadObject(xmlReader, verifyObjectName: true));
                }
            }
        }

        return arguments.ToArray();
    }
```

The above function works fine when data contract object has simple data types like

```
       [OperationContract]
       double Add(double x, double y);
```

with xml as

```
     <Add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <x>12</x>
        <y>10</y>
    </Add>
```

but it doesn't work for object like

```
    <TestLocation xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <location>
             <zip_code>85379</zip_code>
         </location>
    </TestLocation>
```

The line serializer.ReadObject returns the object location with zip_code as null and not 85379.

Answer (score 0):

USing XMLSerializer solved the problem

```
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(parameters[i].ParameterType, 
                                  operation.Contract.Namespace);

    arguments.Add(xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlReader));
```